# Ionic: Image not shown when running on device

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I've set background image for a div in my `scss` file:

```
#header {
  background-image: url('/assets/images/background/bg1.jpg')!important;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 100px;
}
```

The `assets` directory is under `src`, next to `pages`.

The image is shown when I use `ionic serve` and `ionic cordova run android -lc`. But when running the app on device using `ionic cordova run android`, the image is not shown. I've read almost all the similar questions regarding this issue and all of them point out that relative addresses should be avoided and the path should start with `assets`. I tested my path to start with `assets` and it does not show anything (even with `ionic serve`, because it tries to load the image from `http://localhost:8100/build/assets/images/background/bg1.jpg`). But starting the path with `/assets` works and loads the image from `http://localhost:8100/assets/images/background/bg1.jpg`.

How can I fix this? How to make the image appear on the device when not using `-lc`?

P.S. This is the directory structure under `src`:

```
├───app
├───assets
│   ├───fonts
│   │   └───custom
│   ├───i18n
│   ├───icon
│   └───images
│       ├───background
│       └───markers
├───components
│   └───progress-bar
├───models
├───pages
│   ├───friends
│   ├───home
│   ├───login
│   ├───map
│   ├───tabs
│   └───items
├───providers
│   ├───alert
│   ├───map
│   └───message
└───theme
```

My `scss` file is under the `pages/items` directory. Additional tests gave me the following results indicating in which conditions the image was shown:

```
+------------------+-------------+-----------------+-------------+
| Path starts with | ionic serve | run android -lc | run android |
+------------------+-------------+-----------------+-------------+
| assets           | No          | No              | No          |
| /assets          | Yes         | Yes             | No          |
| ./assets         | No          | No              | No          |
| ../assets        | Yes         | Yes             | Yes         |
| ../../assets     | Yes         | Yes             | No          |
+------------------+-------------+-----------------+-------------+
```

Well, as you can see, `../assets/images/background/bg1.jpg` is shown in all conditions, which is against my expectation! Does anybody know the reason?

**Update**:
I extracted the generated `apk` file and here is the directory tree in it revealed:

```
├───assets
│   ├───fonts
│   │   └───custom
│   ├───i18n
│   ├───icon
│   └───images
│       ├───background
│       └───markers
├───build
├───cordova-js-src
│   ├───android
│   └───plugin
│       └───android
└───plugins
    ├───cordova-plugin-camera
    │   └───www
    ├───cordova-plugin-device
    │   └───www
    ├───cordova-plugin-file
    │   └───www
    │       └───android
    ├───cordova-plugin-file-transfer
    │   └───www
    ├───cordova-plugin-geolocation
    │   └───www
    │       └───android
    ├───cordova-plugin-googlemaps
    │   └───www
    ├───cordova-plugin-splashscreen
    │   └───www
    ├───cordova-plugin-statusbar
    │   └───www
    └───ionic-plugin-keyboard
        └───www
            └───android
```

All the `scss` files have been merged into a single file called `main.css` which is located under the `build` directory along with many other `js` files. And as can be seen in the tree, `assets` is located next to the `build` directory. So to get to the background image from the `main.css` file, it's clear that we should take this path: `../assets/images/background/bg1.jpg`, that's why all are `YES` for the 4th record in the table. Now the question is why everybody is advising against using relative path and is insisting to use absolute path? Absolute path wont work this way!

Comment: may i know your scss file path ?

Comment: @Chandru Updated the question with more details

Comment: Try like this it's working for me **background-image: url('../../assets/images/background/1.png');**

Comment: I will updated my answer hope this will helpful you

Answer (score 1):

You can open your apk file and to determine right path for your image. You can open apk via a file archiver.
I recommend to use "Remote Devices" of browser Chrome as well. It will save a lot of your time. Good luck))

Comment: Great advice! I will take a look into the apk file.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the path as shown below. **i.e.** use `./assets/`

```
background-image: url('./assets/images/background/bg1.jpg')!important;
```

Comment: `./assets` does not work either. It tries to load the image from `http://localhost:8100/build/assets/images/background/bg1.jpg` and fails.

Comment: I tested it on browser with `ionic serve` and on device with `ionic cordova run android -lc` and `ionic cordova run android`. None of them showed the image when starting the path with `./assets/`

Comment: Try this `CLI` : `ionic cordova run android --prod --device`

Comment: I couldn't run `ionic cordova run android --prod --device` because I got an error whose reason is unknown to me "_Cannot read property 'assertNoMembers' of undefined_". By the way, I updated the question with more details.

Comment: You need to find out a solution for that error.Otherwise, you cannot release it to the app store. Maybe an `AOT` issue.

Comment: Ok I fixed the problem and ran that command. Still not shown.

Comment: Can you try like this `background-image: url('./assets/images/bg1.jpg')`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156126/discussion-between-meysam-and-sampath).

Answer (score 0):

Updated Latest Answer :

Image file contain the following location :

```
src => assets => images => background => bg1.jpg
```

And the scss file contain the below location :

```
scr => pages => items => items.scss
```

for example inside the items folder

```
1. items.html
2. items.scss
3. items.ts
```

my exmaple is :

**items.html**

```
<div id="header"></div>
```

**items.scss**

problem is : change the url path **background-image: url('../../assets/images/background/bg1.jpg');** instead of background-image: url('/assets/images/background/bg1.jpg')!important;

```
#header {
  background-image: url('../../assets/images/background/1.png');
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 100px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks but as you can see in the table I have provided, `../../assets` path only works with `ionic serve` and `ionic cordova run android -lc`, but when using `ionic cordova run android` no image is shown.

Answer (score 0):

I use

`background-image: url('../assets/images/background/image_name.png');`

instead of

`background-image: url('../../assets/images/background/1.png');`
and it work for me, hope it'll also work for you.